# Not able to install prometheus on Mac os

Tags: macos, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have downloaded prometheus-2.36.2.darwin-amd64.tar.gz file in my Mac system with a M1 processor. But I am unable to install and run prometheus. Please let me know the steps to install the same.

Comment: Do you have an Intel or M1 Mac? What is the failure during installation please describe the steps and the failure.

Comment: Its M1 pro. I have unzipped the above binary. Afterwards, when i tried to launch the prometheus UI.Its not coming up. I am not aware of any other steps that need to be executed to install this.Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an M1 Mac and you try to install an amd64 image. So the processors instruction does not map to the installing image.

You have to download an Image for the M1 architecture.

You can also try to install it with `brew install prometheus`.

Otherwise you may run it in an docker container which you find here:
https://hub.docker.com/u/prom

Comment: Thanks @popeinvestor. brew install worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

There are binaries for your platform available:

1. Go to https://prometheus.io/download/
2. Choose `darwin` as your Operating System and `arm64` as your Architecture.
3. Download the files you need.

Or, use this direct download link: [Prometheus 2.36.2 for macOS on M1](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/download/v2.36.2/prometheus-2.36.2.darwin-arm64.tar.gz).

Answer (score 0):

Installation files are available at: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases

I don't know why there are more installation files for more platforms
available at:

https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases

than at:

https://prometheus.io/download/#prometheus